# Occasional OutOfMemoryException on Bitmap Processing Over The Network

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing, linqpad, linqpad5

I'm running the following code in LinqPad 5:

```
var client = new MongoClient(@"mongodb://192.168.0.108:27017");
var db = client.GetDatabase("Stfc");
var fitCollection = db.GetCollection<ModelFit>("RecentFits");
var fits = fitCollection.AsQueryable();
var captureCollection = db.GetCollection<Capture>("Captures");
var captures = captureCollection.AsQueryable();
var classificationCollection = db.GetCollection<Classification>("Classifications");
var classifications = classificationCollection.AsQueryable();

var modelsDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\iansdesktop\Shared\Stfc\mymodels");
var imagesDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\iansdesktop\Shared\Stfc\Images");

var classificationDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Ian\Documents\Projects\Output\StfcBot\Classification");

var capturesById = captures.ToDictionary(x => x.Id);

var systems = classifications
    .Where(x => x.Label == "system");
var count = systems.Count();
var i = 0;
var pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));

foreach (var classification in systems)
{
    var capture = capturesById[classification.CaptureId];
    var img = imagesDir.File(capture.ImageName);
    
    var srcFile = imagesDir.File(capture.ImageName);
    var destFile = classificationDir.File(capture.ImageName);
    
    
    
    while (!destFile.Exists)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(srcFile.FullName))
            using (var dest = new Bitmap(bmp))
            {
                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(dest))
                {
                    g.DrawEllipse(pen, capture.X - 20, capture.Y - 20, 40, 40);
                }
                dest.Save(destFile.FullName);
                dest.Dispose();
                bmp.Dispose();
            }

            destFile.Refresh();
            destFile.Name.Dump();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.Dump();
            Thread.Sleep(30_000);
        }
    }
    ++i;
    if (i % 10 == 0)
    {
        i.ToProgressSummary(count).Dump();
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything, or could this be a bug in LinqPad?

Comment: You aren't showing the entire script. Where is destFile coming from?

Comment: @Crowcoder I've added more of the script, I tried to cut it down to relevant code for brevity as the OOM isn't coming from the rest of the script

Comment: I think if you step through your code you will be able to see what is happening. The loop within a loop is almost certainly relevant to the issue but I don't know what extensions you are using since DirectoryInfo does not have a File() method and whatever that returns has an Exists property.

Comment: @Crowcoder I found the problem, nothing to do with loops or extension methods. See why answer.

Comment: Without the loop it would not have been piling up resources. I was not implying that there is a bug in the implementation of `while`. One should always code defensively.

Comment: @Crowcoder it was nothing to do with the loop, it happens without it if you can force the right conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is because the bitmap was being loaded from a network path, and the network was occasionally disconnecting.

The documentation states:

```
You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Bitmap.
```

[Bitmap Constructors (See Remarks)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

The OOM exception obfuscates what is going on for some reason, but the underlying stream was being closed.

The solution is to copy the file locally and operate on that local copy:

```
        var tmpFile = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetTempPath()).File(srcFile.Name);
        
        while (!destFile.Exists)
        {
            srcFile.CopyTo(tmpFile.FullName);
            try
            {
                using (var bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(tmpFile.FullName))
                using (var dest = new Bitmap(bmp))
                {
.
                }

                destFile.Refresh();
                destFile.Name.Dump();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
...
            }
            finally
            {
                tmpFile.Delete();
            }
}
```

Of course if the network still disconnects an exception occurs, but at least it's a sensible and understandable error instead of OOM.